# Too late for upgrading 17.04 to 17.10?

Tags: upgrade

Today I noticed the support for my current Ubuntu version has expired (17.04).
To upgrade, I tried apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade, but most of the  Zesty repositories don't work anymore. (does no longer have a Release file)
My update manager and software manager don't give an indication for upgrading at all, refreshing does not work anymore.

Am I stuck with this version or could I still upgrade some way?

Comment: 17.04 ended 13-Jan-2018, and you should have been prompted for some time to upgrade to 17.10.  After EOL the repos are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-release.ubuntu.com` (hence 404 errors you didn't mention) which can be dealt with via link already provided.  If you're offered an release-upgrade on a non-LTS take it, or stick to LTS versions.

Comment: "or could I still upgrade some way?" No, but you can re-install. Maybe this time set your system up such that / and /home/ hold no personal data. That way you can always format / and /home/ for a new install and mount the partition with personal data. I myself don't bother with upgrades anymore. A reinstall takes my system less than 20 minutes (and that includes post-install actions)